# How to host a website in multiple countries for fast response times

Tags: web-hosting, multiple-domains

I have an eCommerce store and it sells digital downloads. The website is hosted in the US, but I have a large customer base that is outside the United States in different countries.

I know the hosting here will be fast for US customers, but how can I make it fast for viewers all around the world? Because when someone outside the US accesses the website, the request will always go to the US data center. Is it possible that when the site is accessed from outside US (e.g: UK), the request should go to UK (or nearest) data center?

If I buy different TLD's `.co.uk`, `.com` etc. for different countries (but should target same website), then is it possible that in UK, it should open `.co.uk`. I can achieve it using IP locator and redirect the user to the respective URL? But how does the request go to the nearest server?

Is it possible via CDN, cloud, cloud hosting, or something else? How can I achieve this goal?

Comment: check into various CDN's (content delivery networks)

Comment: I have checked but it seems that they provide service for static contents. Means I can save all my digitals, js, CSSs, images etc to CDN but I am not sure about this type of dynamic hosting service.

Answer (score 2):

What you ask for can be clearly delivered by a Content Delivery Network (CDN). A typical CDN does route requests to the nearest cached hosted version of your content on the CDN's network of servers.

Caching is mostly done for static content, but some CDN's also handle dynamic requests, such as delivering and executing PHP, database connections, etc.

For example, [Amazon's Cloudfront](http://gigaom.com/2012/05/14/amazon-updates-cdn-for-dynamic-content/) is supposed to be able to handle dynamic content, as well as [Akamai](http://www.akamai.com/html/solutions/luna.html) of course.

Personally, I can recommend Akamai, since that's what I use and works tremendously well for me (including dynamic content and video).

A good overview of what CDN's offer can be found via [CDNPlanet](http://www.cdnplanet.com/cdns/).

Comment: thanks for writing up a full answer on CDN's, didn't have the time when I was writing my comment, and was hoping somebody would be able to answer it more in depth :)!

Comment: thanks for your answer. I hope this will help me to sort out my problem. & many thanks for the CDN explanation.